# smtp relay only works on gmail accounts

Tags: email, email-server, smtp, printer

I have a client who has a server but does not host their own email.  They have just purchased a MFC and want to scan-to-email.  I have them set up to send mail to gmail, however if they try to send to an email address outside the gmail network it doesn't go through.  I've racked my brain on this all day, what can I do?

Thanks
msindle

Comment: does the MFC send directly via gmail or do you use the server as smarthost which again smarthosts to gmail? what hostname/port did you use as relay? did you enable smtp auth? did you enable encryption (SSL / TLS ) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably haven't configure SMTP authentication from the MFC to Gmail, and so it is connecting as if it's delivering mail to a gmail.com address. This works fine for gmail.com recipients, but for anything else you're asking Gmail to relay the message which it will certainly reject.

You need to create a Gmail account for the MFC and configure it to authenticate with that username and password (and probably use TLS). Otherwise you need to setup a mail server which will relay messages for the MFC.